# Counters and macros?

Tags: macros, tex-core, counters

Not sure how I should post my question but here it is: I've seen that in plain TeX, `\newcount` is illegal inside a macro `\def`inition. Is there a way to allocate a register inside a macro? Also, if I know that I will use a register only once or twice, can I free it after and leave the space for a future `\newcount`?

Comment: It is not illegal, it works: it is just usually a bad idea, you should allocate the counter once and then use it each time in the macro. But if you want do it it works in particular if you are defining a variant declaration form (eg declaring a theorem needs to declare a counter.

Comment: Well, I'm going to jail then

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Plain TeX, `\newcount` is defined as `\outer` so it can't be in the replacement text for a macro. The idea is that a macro should never define a new counter, although this isn't true in every occasion, but I'll do an example later.

The main reason for this is that you can't "free" the register after having allocated it. I *could* be possible, but what about other macros that might have defined to access it? The best strategy is to use symbolic names (what `\newcount` does) and never care about the actual register number.

If you need a counter for temporary storage, just use `\count255` (which is aliased to `\count@`) or, in a group, any other count register. In more complex cases you can allocate a temporary counter yourself and use it as many times as you wish.

---

Here's an example of a “legitimate” call of `\newcount` in a definition. Suppose you want to define distinct counters for different logical structures (like LaTeX does for `\newtheorem`). So you want to define a command

```
\newtheorem{<name>}{<label>}
```

so that `\<name>` is defined and a counter is allocated.

```
\def\newtheorem#1#2{%
  \outer\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{%
    \par\medskip\noindent
    \global\advance\csname thmcnt#1\endcsname by 1
    {\bf\number\csname thmcnt#1\endcsname\ #2}%
    \enspace\begingroup\it \ignorespaces}
  \outer\expandafter\def\csname end#1\endcsname{\endgroup\par\medskip}
  \csname newcount\expandafter\endcsname\csname thmcnt#1\endcsname
}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\lem
Something preliminary.
\endlem

\thm
The big result.
\endthm

\thm
Another big result.
\endthm

\bye
```

[image]

This is just an example, of course; numbering of theorems should be independent of the label. If you look closely, you see how to fool TeX so that an `\outer` macro is used in the replacement text.

Comment: Thanks! I'll review the expansion rules more closely. Btw it _could_ be possible to define \freecount, \freeskip etc for TeX if \newcount were redefined to allocate a number in function of the previously free'd registers, am I right?

Comment: @lvaneesbeeck Not really. One would have to maintain a catalog of the allocation numbers and of the associated names. But you can always say `\newcount\foo` and then `\let\baz\foo` and this would give headaches, at the least.

Answer (score 7):

It is not illegal, this works without error:

```
\newcommand\foo{\newcounter{zz}}

\foo

\setcounter{zz}{2}



\stop
```

However it is almost always better not to do this and to allocate the counter once, amd just use it in each macro.

I assume that you mean LaTeX (as you used `\newcounter`) If on the other hand you mean the plain TeX `\newcount` that is different as it is an `\outer` macro to stop you using it.
It is possible to work around that, However the same applies that it is almost always better not to do so.

the standard allocation system used in plain and latex does not allow for freeing unused allocations. It is a simple increment. In classic TeX there are only 256 count registers so you can easily run out, etex allows several thousand so it is less of a problem there.